# Tata Photon Plus not working in Ubuntu 12.04 though configured and was running once upon a time.

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, usb-modem

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 few months back. My modem, Tata Photon Plus got connected after a number of unsuccessful trials and I browsed the net successfully.

But since a month, it is not getting connected. Whenever I try to connect, it shows this msg:

> CDMA Network
>   You are registered on the home device

and

> Modem Network-Disconnected, you are offline

The network signals are completely ok as I am using the same device in Windows 7. I plug in the modem every time I try to connect it.

Please help me out.

Comment: What username and password did you used?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem faced. After many hit and trials found a trick that is working for me. I change the port once it gives that problem and restart. Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The steps for using Tata Photon+ on ubuntu are-

1. First connect tata photon on any windows machine. Open the device through Windows Explorer. Copy directory Linux and file install_linux from it on to any usb pendrive and then via it copy them into your home directory in Ubuntu. Now connect tata photon+ to ubuntu.
2. Open terminal and become `root` user
3. Change permissions as executable of file install_linux by command `chmod 777 install_linux`
4. Run this file(which is a shell script) as `./install_linux`
5. The script will run and then a prompt will appear. Press <kbd>enter</kbd> on the prompt.
6. Follow some on screen instructions on terminal (if any)
7. After this is complete Photon+ will be installed at path `/usr/local/Photon_Plus`
8. Finally fire a command `/usr/local/Photon_Plus/MobilePartner`
9. This will pop the Tata Photon startup window same as in Windows through which you can Connect.

   - Help for this is provided in `README` file in the Linux directory

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to go through the installation process specified in the other answer, just connect your dongle to a windows machine first and change the setting from "Photon+ mode" to "Hybrid mode". This will allow ubuntu to access the modem.

Once you do that, login to ubuntu and your modem will be detected by the NetworkManager. Proceed with creating a new mobile-broadband connection through a dialog like the one below. Once the connection is created, you will able to use it to connect to internet using your photon+ dongle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with mts mblaze it often get disconnected while photon + works fine on the same device.

this might help 
1. reboot the system before you plug your usb drive(work for me in mblaze).
2.Enter the username and password as "internet" by editing network connection.